# How to avoid binding error in dropdown due to an extra property in on item in list?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a drodown...and a list of three items bound to it - A,B and C.

Both of these derive from same class - ViewModelBase.

B has a property "IsSomethingEnabled". A and C do not have this property.

In the trigger of this dropdown...I have a data trigger...and it is based on the property - "IsSomethingEnabled".

But I get data binding error as this property is not there in A and C.

How do I solve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have fixed using below code - Is this right way to do?

```
  <DataTrigger Value="False">
                                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="True">
                                                    <Binding Path="IsSomethingenabled" />
                                                </PriorityBinding>
                                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I think that the prioritybinging is more a trick but I recently discover it and it is a good tool for your toolbox. Anyway if it is a new design I would prefer to take the DataTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 0):

You could [specify a separate DataTemplate for each type of item](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ee71a113-0abb-4823-8c0c-7056d6df7bdc/) by specifying a DataTemplate per type or implementing a a DataTemplate selector.